# Google Sheets - Transpose 2D table to 1D List

Tags: google-sheets, split, datatable, formatting, flatten

I'll make an example with a Pokémon table type that corresponds exactly to my data structure.

On the 18 types present line 1 (representing the attacker single type),
I have to convert the duos of types ( representing the attacked )
So I have to get rid of the attacker line and transform it into a column.

This will transform :

```
Normal none 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1....
```

(total of 18duos of types squared I have 324 rows + 1 row of attackers)

Into :

```
Normal none Normal 1
Normal none Fire 1
Normal none Water 1
Normal none Electric 1
Normal none Grass 1
Normal none Ice 1
Normal none Fighting 2
```

(Here we do trios of types, a total of 18 cubed : 5832 lines )

Here is an overview of the starting point.

Thanks a lot to those who want to look into this :)!

[image: Table Screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(A2:A&"×"&B2:B&"×"&C1:T1&"×"&C2:T), "×"), 
 "where Col4 is not null", ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(A2:A="",,A2:A&"x"&B2:B&"<-"&C1:T1&":"&C2:T)),"select Col1 where Col1 is not null",0),":"))
```